# VBA: Substitute() works on string but not on Cell contents

Tags: vba, excel, substitution

I've got a cell which contains the string "Tom, Adam, Ben, Sarah".
I am trying to put each of these items into an array.
The Split() function does not seem to work with ", " as a delimiter; only ","

Therefore, I am trying to remove spaces from the string/cell before using Split(). In this case, I am using the Substitute() function because Replace() does not seem to work.

```
workingCell = "Tom, Adam, Ben, Sarah"
workingCell1 = Range("C4") 'contains: Tom, Adam, Ben, Sarah

workingCell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(workingCell, " ", "")   'removes all spaces
workingCell1 = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(workingCell1, " ", "") 'retains all spaces

splitArr = VBA.Split(workingCell1, ",")

For Each element In splitArr
    Debug.Print (element)
Next
```

It seems that Range("C4") is not being taken as a value, and is not treated as a string. Using Range("C4").Value does not work either.

Comment: Your formula works perfectly for me

Comment: It doesn't seem to actually remove spaces. When I split the resulting String, each element after the first has a space in front of it.

Comment: can you show your split code also?

Comment: I've added it to the OP

Comment: Just add this to a msgbox `splitArr(0) & splitArr(1) & splitArr(2) & splitArr(3)` . Its just printing fine

Comment: Yes the output looks good, but I want all spaces to be removed. The message displayed shows spaces between the elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145053/discussion-between-gowtham-shiva-and-tawm).

Comment: Try the replace format instead of substitute.  workingCell = replace(workingCell, " ", "") and also see if changing "workingCell1 = Range("C4")" to something like "workingCell1 = Range("C4").Value might make a difference"  If you didn't declare workingCell1 as a string then it might have made it a range object or variant.

Comment: obviously the character is not space. You can try to clean the text before splitting `splitArr = Split([clean(C4)], ", ")`

Comment: I'd suspect you had an ANSI 160 character - often happens with data form the web. Using `Replace(text, chr(160), "")` would work for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove the spaces.  Just include them as part of the delimiter in the Split function.

```
workingCell1 = Range("C4") 'contains: Tom, Adam, Ben, Sarah
splitArr = VBA.Split(workingCell1, ", ")

For Each element In splitArr
    Debug.Print (element)
Next
```

Note the space after the comma in the delimiter argument in this line:

```
splitArr = VBA.Split(workingCell1, ", ")
```

Comment: That was my original solution, but that seems to not split the string at all. The result in my splitArr is a single element "Tom, Adam, Ben, Sarah"

Comment: Hmm.  It works for me.  Are you sure that the value in Range("C4") is what you think it is?

Comment: Hmm, I just re-wrote the string in the Cell and it works fine. I'm not sure what is wrong with the formatting of the original string, but this seems to be an issues with the source data, not the VBA.